# Defining function then calling back if no answer: Elixir

Tags: function, elixir

Trying to call back the function if there is no response. Is this more of an object-oriented thing?

```
defmodule ask do
 def getAlt(altitudeSet) do

  altitudeSet = IO.gets"altitudeSet"

  case altitudeSet do
    altitudeSet when altitudeSet in ["Y\n","y\n"]->
      IO.puts "You selcted #{altitudeSet}"
    altitudeSet when altitudeSet in ["N\n","n\n"]->
      IO.puts "You selected #{altitudeSet}"
    _->
     ask.getAlt()
   end

 end
end
```

and I get this:

```
warning: variable "ask" does not exist and is being expanded to "ask()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name newGlennHopperScript.exs:9 ** (CompileError) newGlennHopperScript.exs:9: undefined function ask/0
(stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
(elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.defmodule/2
newGlennHopperScript.exs:9: (file)
```

Comment: Use `Ask` rather than `ask` - modules must begin with an Uppercase letter in Elixir

Answer (score 0):

The module name must be written capitalized.

Just replace the first line

```
defmodule ask do
```

with

```
defmodule Ask do
```

About calling back functions recursively: This is not at all necessarily related to object orientation and there are lots of cases where such usage is common in Elixir. You can however just call `getAlt()` instead of prefixing it with the module name (`Alt.getAlt()`), as you are doing it within the same module.

As a side remark: camel-case is not commonly used in Elixir. Your function should usually rather be called `get_alt()`.